# Gradle build tools.jar not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, amazon-ec2, build.gradle

I am trying to build spring boot application in RHEL EC2 machine.I am getting could not find "tools.jar" in gradle build

```
readlink -f $(which java)
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-2.el8_1.x86_64/jre/bin/java

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-2.el8_1.x86_64/jre
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-2.el8_1.x86_64/jre
```

But when i am trying to build i am getting below error

```
$gradle build
 > Task :compileJava FAILED

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
 > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09- 
 2.el8_1.x86_64/jre contains a valid JDK installation.

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
 log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: You have a jre not a jdk installed.

Comment: @ M. Deinum  I installed JDK which path should i give in export command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed jdk and the ran $yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.After this build was successfull using same jre path